# filtro de datos entre 2 fechas Spring Boot (Usando: findByStartDateBetween)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hola a todos yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema, e intentado todo espero me puedan ayudar. Desde ya muchas gracias.

### Model

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "personas")
@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String apellido;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 10)
    private String dni;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "fecha_alta")
    private LocalDateTime fechaAlta;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "fecha_modificacion")
    private LocalDateTime fechaModificacion;

    @PrePersist
    private void antesDePersistir(){
        this.fechaAlta = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void antesDeUpdate(){
        this.fechaModificacion = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
@GetMapping("/persons/get/")
public List<Person> getByStartDateBetween(@RequestParam(name = "from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDateTime from,
                                          @RequestParam (name = "to") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDateTime to) {
    return repository.findByFechaAltaBetween(from, to);
```

### Repository

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("select p from Person p where p.fechaAlta >= :from and p.fechaAlta <= :to ")
List<Person> findByFechaAltaBetween(@Param("from") LocalDateTime from, @Param("to") LocalDateTime to);
```

Postman
----------------------------------------------------------------------------[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Error

"message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2022-02-01'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-02-01]",
"path": "/api/persons/get/"

### BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gente Disculpen las molestias. Luego de un rato y de seguir investigando aca traigo lo que, la solución.

El controller debe que dar asi:

```
@GetMapping("/persons/get/")
public List<Person> getByStartDateBetween(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm") LocalDateTime from,
                                          @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm") LocalDateTime to) {
    return repository.findByFechaAltaBetween(from, to);
}
```

El Repository lo dejamos de esta froma:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("select p from Person p where p.fechaAlta BETWEEN :from and :to ")
List<Person> findByFechaAltaBetween(@Param("from") LocalDateTime from, @Param("to") LocalDateTime to);
```

}

y el postman se debe pasar de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Espero le funciones y le sirva, si es asi dejen su comentarios y si tenes otra, solucion compartan. Muchas gracias.